# Buffer.swap16 is not a function

Tags: node.js, meteor, buffer

I've tested some buffer swap function in NodeJS, but in my Meteor project it doesn't work.

Can somebody tell me the reason?

Nodejs:

```js
var CRC = new Buffer([0x20,0x40]);
console.log(CRC.swap16());   //  OUTPUT:  <Buffer 40 20>
```

Meteor.js

```js
var CRC = new Buffer([0x20,0x40]);
console.log(CRC.swap16());   //  OUTPUT:  TypeError: CRC.swap16 is not a function
```

Can somebody help me please. In know it's maybe a version problem. but i can't solve it at the moment.

Is there also a way to get this thing running with meteor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Buffer.swap16()`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_swap16) method has been added in 5.10.0, whereas Meteor uses NodeJS version 4.

You can copy this method implementation from the [NodeJS source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/buffer.js#L1500-L1513), it is quite simple (with small modifications):

```js
function swap(b, n, m) {
  const i = b[n];
  b[n] = b[m];
  b[m] = i;
}

Buffer.prototype.swap16 = function swap16() {
  const len = this.length;
  if (len % 2 !== 0) {
    throw new RangeError('ERR_INVALID_BUFFER_SIZE', '16-bits');
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
    swap(this, i, i + 1);
  }
  return this;
};
```